# How can I review manually resolved conflicts in git (github, some app, InteliJ)

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging, merge-conflict-resolution

As for me, manually resolved conflicts are one of the biggest sources of bugs.

Currently we are resolving conflicts gathering loudly in front of one monitor, which I concider to be the stone age practice. Moreover, after saving and closing the visual diff tool, we can not return to conflict view later, if we want to double-review or fix something.

I am looking for a way to quickly review all latest manually-resolved conflicts in git.

**I would like to see A-branch, B-branch and resulting piece of code for every conflict.**

I can manually give the desided tool the commit number, or I can see conflicts in a list.

---

Offtopic:

My great idea is to introduce merge-reviewing if a conflict happened. All the developers responsible for that part of code (in both branches) should review the conflict, especially when they are working remotely. What about alowing merge only after confirmation from both sides?

Comment: +1 for the idea of merge-review!

Answer (score 2):

I feel these "shouting matches" could perhaps be avoided by changing the workflow. Say a developer is working on a topic branch, and he gets behind `master`.

```
A--B--C--D--E--F
       \
        X--Y--Z
```

Instead of him or the group coming up with a merge commit, he can just rebase his changes onto his local `master`

```
 A--B--C--D--E--F
                 \
                  X'--Y'--Z'
```

Then when the time is right it will allow for a clean merge commit to "official" master

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--X'--Y'--Z'
```

[**ref**](http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Topic-Branches)

Answer (score 2):

That’s pretty easy with git:

```
git log --patch -c -1 YOURMERGE
```

That will output something like this:

```
index ea575f9,b943345..239a586
--- a/file-with-conflicts.txt
+++ b/file-with-conflicts.txt
@@@ -1,1 -1,1 +1,1 @@@
- Version A
 -Version B
++Merge Resolution
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `git help log` page :

`git log --patch -c -1 <commit-id>`

> -c
>        With this option, diff output for a merge commit shows the differences from each of the parents to the merge result
>   simultaneously instead of showing pairwise diff between a parent and
>   the result one at
>        a time. Furthermore, it lists only files which were modified from all parents.
>
> -p, -u, --patch
>       Generate patch (see section on generating patches).